# Scope variable not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have scope variables set in my controller

```
$scope.patientState = {};
var dateTime = new Date();
$scope.today = moment(dateTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
$scope.patientState.stateChangeDate = new Date();
```

These I am using in my view for setting the default value of a date:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="patientState.stateChangeDate" max="{{today}}"/>
```

Next I am displaying the scope variable in the view as

```
{{patientState.stateChangeDate}}
```

My question is when I set the "max" parameter in the input tag I am not able to see the scope variable displayed i.e {patientState.stateChangeDate}} doesn't display anything.

But if remove the "max" parameter from the input tag I am able to see the scope variable displayed.

I am not able to figure out why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set max date is today and select previous date then it will get updated in the $scope variable but if you select feature days then the field validation will be false and it will not set the date variable.

Looks like it removes the entire variable from the scope when ivalidated.

You can also check inspect the input field is being added with the css class "ng-invalid"

Add the below css to your input and see, whenever you don't get the template value the field will be invalid (red).

```
input {
    transition:all linear 0.5s;
    background: transparent;
}
input.ng-invalid {
    color:white;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel the issue is because you had formatted `$scope.today` date

Convert both of them( `$scope.today` & `$scope.patientState.stateChangeDate`) in same format and check if your problem is solved!

Issue here is when you formatted `$scope.today` to `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format, the `value of today is converted for 12AM`. But your `$scope.patientState.stateChangeDate` is `current time` which is always greater than `$scope.today`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I checked. If I roll back to previous dates, it works.